# Why is the units of gasUsed in the transaction receipt 10^11 Wei?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, gas, receipts

I'm checking the balance of an account after a `payable` transaction in a Truffle test. Below is my code:

```
// amount is the value supplied to the txn
assert.equal(Number(String(currentBalance)),
             Number(String(previousBalance)) + amount - (gasUsed * 100000000000),
            'Account balance for ' + String(acct) + ' incorrect after txn.');
// previous account bal: 99965457999999999000
// current account bal: 99954881999999998000
// gasUsed: 105760
// amount: 1000
```

As you can see, I have to multiply the `gasUsed` value by `10^11` or my test will fail... I don't really understand why it's `10^11`? GWEI (`10^9`) makes a lot more sense. At least a multiple of 3 right? This isn't in the [web3 documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=receipt) at all.

EDIT: to clarify I'm trying to figure out what `gasUsed` is and if web3 or Truffle are overwriting the default gas price. The gas price according to my Ganache interface is 20000000000, which doesn't work with my calculations. That's why I was lead to believe `gasUsed` is the total txn fee in wei.

Comment: Can you give us the actual value returned?

Comment: I just added the values of all variables!

Answer (score 2):

Gas is not ether. Gas is used to estimate the work made by the EVM. It has nothing to do with weis/ether etc...

If you want to know how much ether is worth this gas, multiply it by the gasPrice value.

Comment: And from your calculation, it sounds like your gas price is probably 100 gwei (10^11 wei).

Comment: That's what I initially thought too, but I'm using Ganache and according to the Ganache interface, my gas price is 20000000000 by default. Does web3 overwrite this with it's own default

Comment: If gasPrice is not provided in the transaction object, geth will get the gas price from the EVM itself when processing the transaction.

Comment: Ok maybe this should be a question about Ganache and it's misleading interface then